# Как отсортировать данные в txt файле?

Tags: python

В первом файле содержатся разные (одинаковых нет) ip адреса
Во втором содержаться записи по типу:

`55.145.78.252 28/Feb/2020:06:27:33 +0100 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)"`

Как отсортировать данные во втором файле, чтобы они были отсортированы по ip из первого файла?
Например был взят 55.145.78.252 адрес и во втором файле с таким ip есть 10 записей по всему файлу. Чтобы он записал эти записи и дальше перешел к следующему адресу

Comment: а файлы большие?

Comment: нет, всего строк около 30000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
with open("ips.txt", "r") as fp:
    ips = list(map(str.rstrip, fp))  # Считываем из файла все адреса

with open("records.txt", "r") as fp:
    records = list(map(str.rstrip, fp))  # Считываем из другого файла записи

records.sort(key=lambda x: ips.index(x.split()[0]))  # Сортируем записи по нахождению адреса в списке адресов

with open("sorted_records.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write("\n".join(records))  # Записываем отсортированные записи
```

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм таков(не самый лучший наверное):
1)Берете ip из первого файла
2)Сравниваете все записи из второго файла с выбранным ip
3)Найденные записи записываете в массив
4)Массив записываете в новый конечный файл
5)зацикливаете эти действия,только массив с новыми данными вы дозаписываете в конечный файл

Answer (score 0):

Отсортировать один раз свой второй файл по ip.   Можно еще предварительно сгруппировав. Потом в цикле ищете, что вам надо. Если циклов много -  так будет точно быстрее, чем линейно просматривать неотсортированный файл при каждом проходе цикла.